# How to debug 404 on user/login user/register user/logout?

Tags: 8, debugging, uri

I have a Drupal 8 site on 8.4.2.  When I upgrade it to 8.5.1, after running the database updates, the paths `/user/register`, `/user/login`, and `/user/logout` return a 404.

- I can log in with Drush (`drush uli myuser`), so it is possible to actually log in, but the log in page is not displayed.
- I tried uninstalling my custom modules, but the problem persists.
- I looked at `/admin/reports/dblog`, but it just says "page not found" as the error for `/user/login`.

This [question about a similar problem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5102/page-not-found-on-user-login-and-user-register) was closed as off topic because it was too specific; my question is about "how can I debug this?" not "what is the cause of my problem?"

Comment: I have exactly the same problem going from 8.6.4 to 8.5.1...  I'm in the process of making a module to check the routes that exist.

Comment: I checked the routeProvider and the settings match the expected values and exist properly.  Also tried adding some debug stuff into the form that is called and the controller that manages it all.  Nothing shows.  It feels like the symphony router is not getting as far as loading the login process before it gives a 404... more investigations tomorrow.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2018-03-30/since-upgrading-to-851-userlogin-userlogout-userregister added this on the drupal support forum and also put the problem on the Drupal Support group in Facebook.

Comment: Checked with Devel and it says "Unable to load route for url '/user/login'" when checking the user.login route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AndrewKillen:

> Checked with Devel and it says "Unable to load route for url
>   '/user/login'" when checking the user.login route.

How this could be debugged (on an working example, because I don't have a broken site):

Enable Xdebug and go to the url: /devel/routes/item?path=/user/login

*Drupal\devel\Controller\RouteInfoController::routeDetail:*

```
  public function routeDetail(Request $request, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $route = NULL;

    // Get the route object from the path query string if available.
    if ($path = $request->query->get('path')) {
      try {
        $route = $this->router->match($path);
```

Set a breakpoint for the last line and step into `match($path)`. Then after a new request with the path info is created you get to:

*Router::matchRequest:*

```
  public function matchRequest(Request $request) {
    $collection = $this->getInitialRouteCollection($request);
    if ($collection->count() === 0) {
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException(sprintf('No routes found for "%s".', $this->currentPath->getPath()));
    }
    $collection = $this->applyRouteFilters($collection, $request);

    if ($ret = $this->matchCollection(rawurldecode($this->currentPath->getPath($request)), $collection)) {
      return $this->applyRouteEnhancers($ret, $request);
    }
```

`getInitialRouteCollection()` results in three possible matches:

- user.login
- user.login.http
- entity.user.canonical

The second one is filtered in `applyRouteFilters()` because this is POST only and for JSON. The entity route is removed after the compiled routes are matched in `matchCollection()` because "login" is not a valid user.

And so the route user.login is the last one remaining and returned. If not you have to check where on this way the route is not collected or filtered out.

Comment: the problem (thanks to luis below) is that we had a view that is on /user/% that normally showed the Author stories as a list when clicking on the authors name on an article, and also re-direct from /user/UID to /author/author-name. 

Removing that view allows for the login/logout/register to be visible.

Comment: OK, in this case you would have seen this view route while debugging the route match.

Comment: @4x4 I'm still going to go through the debug process to see that things are truely fixed and we are dealing with these overview pages properly along with the login/logout pages.  Many thanks indeed for your time and help

Comment: Thanks Andrew - that was it for me as well. Commenting just in case anyone else hits this snag - I had a view set to /user/content and even that was messing with the default routing of /user. Changed from /user/content to /content/all and voila, it works again.